# Mask lower triangluar portion of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a dataframe output I'm generating, which is a 5 x 5 correlation matrix.

```
     A         B          C          D          E
A    1.00000  -0.277360   0.653920  -0.479600   0.513890
B   -0.27736   1.000000  -0.790648   0.885801  -0.482763
C    0.65392  -0.790648   1.000000  -0.876451   0.672148
D   -0.47960   0.885801  -0.876451   1.000000  -0.756182
E    0.51389  -0.482763   0.672148  -0.756182   1.000000
```

I'd like to obtain the overall mean of this dataframe but for that I'd need to ignore duplicate values (leaving only the first occurrence). I tried using

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

However, it returns the df unchanged, which I believe is because `drop_duplicates()` will remove rows, but not replace individual cells with `NaN`.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? (desired output below)

Note that ***I'd also need to specifically remove correlations == 1***, as they are unnecessary.

```
     A         B          C          D          E
A    NaN      -0.277360   0.653920  -0.479600   0.513890
B    NaN       NaN       -0.790648   0.885801  -0.482763
C    NaN       NaN        NaN       -0.876451   0.672148
D    NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN       -0.756182
E    NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: off the top of my head: `numpy.unique(df.values.flatten()).mean()`

Comment: wait, do you want the modified dataframe, or the mean of all unique values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `tril_indices`

```
df.values[np.tril_indices(len(df))]=np.nan
df
    A        B         C         D         E
A NaN -0.27736  0.653920 -0.479600  0.513890
B NaN      NaN -0.790648  0.885801 -0.482763
C NaN      NaN       NaN -0.876451  0.672148
D NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN -0.756182
E NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Efficient masking with `np.indices`:

```
i, j = np.indices(df.shape)
df.values[~(i < j)] = np.nan

df
    A        B         C         D         E
A NaN -0.27736  0.653920 -0.479600  0.513890
B NaN      NaN -0.790648  0.885801 -0.482763
C NaN      NaN       NaN -0.876451  0.672148
D NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN -0.756182
E NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

np.nanmean(df.values)
# -0.09372449999999999
```